# Mysql FULL TEXT index search error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, full-text-search

So I've got full text index added in one of my table's columns, my database engine is MyIsam and I still get this nasty error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list' in... My query:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT loc, lt, lg FROM locations WHERE MATCH(loc) AGAINST(?) ");
```

How to solve this problem and what should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for the definition of the FULLTEXT index. It apparently is defined for more than columns than just the single `loc` column.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE locations\G

CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `loc` text,
  `name` text,
  `summary` text,
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`,`summary`,`loc`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The columns you name in the `MATCH()` function must be *all* the columns for the fulltext index, and they must be in the same order.

Example:

```
-- WRONG; only using one of the three columns
SELECT loc, lt, lg FROM locations WHERE MATCH(loc) AGAINST(?)

-- WRONG; using all three columns, but in a different order than the index
SELECT loc, lt, lg FROM locations WHERE MATCH(loc, name, summary) AGAINST(?)

-- RIGHT:
SELECT loc, lt, lg FROM locations WHERE MATCH(name, summary, loc) AGAINST(?)
```

Comment: I just don't understand FULLTEXT search. The more I use it, the more useless it seems. It has so many restrictions.